# Use Ajax to call php function with paremeters

Tags: php, ajax, function, postdata

First off - **NO JQUERY**. I hate that thing with a passion and I can't possibly imagine how a native code implementation would be less efficient.

What I am after is a way to call any PHP function from Javascript and pass parameters to the function using call_user_func_array. I have written this exact code before but can't think of how I did it.

In the end, I want to be able to (in JS) be able to do something like:

```
var responseString = callPhpFunction(func, param1, param2, etc);
```

`

Which is an ideal and will probably involve a few nested functions. At the moment I have the basic Ajax request. Needs to be POST, and doesn't have to handle multiple requests simultaneously.

```
var lastResponse = '';

function phpFunction(funcName){
var ajaxRequest; 

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert('Ajax/Browser problem!');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

                    //Seems to work.
        window.lastResponse = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'ajaxCall.php', true);
ajaxRequest.send('func='+funcName); //Need to generate parameters dynamically, not sure how to do that
}
```

This shouldn't be really complex, but I've never seen a good implementation of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a real question here, just your request for others to do work for you. Please tell us why you can't write it on your own, what is the problem?

Comment: Yea fair point. I missed that bit. (And sorry I accidentally keep pressing enter, I will update this post)

Comment: I dunno, I just can't get my head around it. When I go to type the response in explaining in more detail, I figure out how to do it. Then when I go to code it I forget.

Give me a bit and I'll have either figured out the answer or a good way of wording my multiple questions. THank you

Comment: That is the typical cycle for a programmer, bear with it as it gets easier with time. Also keep in mind that comments are not for general discussion so let's not go that way here ;).